# What determines how long it will take an imprisoned leader to escape?

Tags: lords-mobile

There are many videos and tutorials discussing how prisons work, but in all of them the wait timer is shown as 3 days before a leader can be executed.  Last night my leader was imprisoned for the first time, but he escaped and returned before I even woke up.  So I assume either my castle level or the attacker's castle or prison level affects how long they can hold my leader.  However, neither my prison nor castle list anything about a maximum hold time.

What determines the length of time a leader can be held before they escape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an online post I found, and then some experience with captured leaders, it appears that castle level plays into the time a leader can be held before they escape.  It seems like IGN thought it would be a good way to ease newer players into the functionality to have it affect their newly lvl 10 castles for only a few hours.